# Matrix indexed by strings instead of integer values

Tags: c++, string, dictionary, stl, matrix

Is it possible in C++ to have a matrix of int values where I can access to these values through string indexes ? Doing something like M["one"]["two"]++; etc.

Comment: You can use a map<string,map<string,int> >

Comment: @Mordachai how do I iterate over values of a map<string,map<string,int> > M; ?

Comment: you would use a nested loop, just as you probably would for a matrix: `for(auto outter = matrix.begin(); outter != matrix.end(); ++outter) for (auto inner = outter.begin(); inner != outter.end(); ++inner) { /* do whatever you want with *inner */ }`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `unordered_map` (in boost or `c++11`) or just `map` in good old `C++`. Make a `unordered_map<string, unordered_map<string, int> >`. Should do the trick.

Comment: Is it possible to just use map<string, map<string, int> > M; and initialize all values of M to 0 without iterating over the map ?

Comment: how do I iterate over values of a map<string,map<string,int> > M; ?

Comment: @shn use an iterator: `for (map<string, map<string, int> >::iterator it = M.begin(); it != M.end(); ++it)`

Comment: It is better to use `std::map<std::pair<std::string, std::string>, int>`, but then the syntax won't be that pretty.

Comment: @Zyx2000 why do you think it would be better?

Comment: Because then you only need one map, which means less overhead (both memory and performance), and at least in my opinion expresses the intent more clearly.

Answer (score 0):

It's not direct, but since you ask, you probably don't know about `operator []()`.
You can define your custom `[]` operator.

Just to explain you the concept behind: you could define a class Row, or Column, owning a `std::vector<int>`. For this class you could define the `operator[]`:

```
class Row
{
public:
    int& operator[](const std::string& );
    //...
    std::vector<int> ints;
}
```

Your class matrix then would own a `std::vector<Row>`

```
class Matrix
{
public:
    Row& operator[](const std::string& );
    //...
    std::vector<Row> rows;
}
```

this would enable you to use the syntax `Matrix m; m["one"]["two"]=2;`

Answer (score 0):

I would keep internal details separate from the user interface.

What if you want to use a different language, for example?

Have a map from the word to the integer:

```
map<string, unsigned int> index;
index["one"] = 1;
// .etc
```

Use the integer on a 2D array, as normal.

```
int x = index["one"];
int y = index["two"];

doSomething(array[x][y]);
```